# How to delete any message that contains specific emojis discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Im working on a discord bot that blocks anything saying uwu, owo, uvu, etc. however, it is possible to bypass this by using emojis. Is there any way to delete a message that has a specific emoji/ specific emojis? here's what ive tried: `':regional_indicator_u: :regional_indicator_w: :regional_indicator_u:'` in a list but that didnt work. copy and pasting the emojis, but it wouldnt let me. typing them out, no emoji for it. please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```js
if (message.content.includes("u")) {
 // ...
}
```

It looks like plain text but it's unicode emojis

Comment: Just a tip: To reference discord's emojis put a backslash directly infront of the emoji and send the message.

Comment: [This](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/regional) is an easy-to-copy-from list of all of the regional indicator letters, as an alternative method of referencing these emotes. Most other unicode characters and emotes can be easily looked up on that website as well.